# java - how do I print out the words in increasing magnitudes, e.g 1st = Our, 2nd = Our greatest, 3rd = our greatest glory

Tags: java

String s2 = "Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.";

String[] split1 = s2.split(" ");

for (String s3 : split1) {
System.out.println(s3 );

```
   }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the implementatio:

```java
String s2 = "Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.";
String[] split1 = s2.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < split1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        System.out.print(split1[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```java
Our 
Our greatest 
Our greatest glory 
Our greatest glory is 
Our greatest glory is not 
Our greatest glory is not in 
Our greatest glory is not in never 
Our greatest glory is not in never falling, 
Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but 
Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in 
Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising 
Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every 
Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time 
Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time we 
Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.
```

Comment: tysm <3<3<3<3<3<3

Comment: Do not simply do other people's homework for them.